# in ASp.NET MVC, How do you remember a dropdownlist's state?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have this action:

```
public ActionResult Add([Bind(Include = "Title,Description")] product product2Add){
--SNIP--
}
```

I'm using a view model pattern where I've created a special `AddProduct_ViewModel` class that contains my product class and anything else I need in my view.  That includes 2 dropdownlists; one that does a DB lookup of all the various product catagories, and another that lists the product suppliers.

When I do validation on my product that fails I cannot see how to easily save the state of my dropdownlists (without doing some lengthy db code).  Is there a better way?

Comment: Do partial requests. This way you won't even need to remember it's state, cause it won't change. :)

Answer (score 1):

in the controller you can call:

```
Request.Form.Get("MyDropDownListId");
```

To get the selected option's value attribute.

While building up the dropdownlist again after postback, you can use this value to re-set the selected item.

**Example** of setting the selected item in the view when you have a property "PageSize" in your Model:

```
Response.Write(Html.DropDownList("pageSize",
            Model.PageSizes.ToSelectList(p => p.ToString(), p => p.ToString(), p => p.Equals(Model.PageSize))));
```

With extension method ToSelectList():

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, string> text, Func<T, string> value, Func<T, bool> selected)
{
    var items = enumerable.Select(f => new SelectListItem() { Text = text(f), Value = value(f) }).ToList();
    return items;
}
```

Comment: In short - controller action should accept ddl data through parameters and pass them back. Right?

Comment: yes you can use a parameter "string MyDropDownListId" or you can use the Request.Form NameValueCollection if you don't want to bother with parameters

Comment: And indeed, you need to pass the selected value back to your view after postback.
You can avoid this using AJAX.

Answer (score -2):

Well.. in MVC there is no viewstate, so controls can't save state, although you can use some tricks with storing it in a cookie using javascript - preferably jquery, or saving this information to the server side in onChange event.